# Can i use one company to host website and different company for email using same domain

Tags: email, website

The domain was purchased with go daddy, website was created on wix and dns linked to that but email will be with ionos. Can this be done? and if so how do I do it?

Comment: Yes, can be done via DNS records. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

For serving web site you set up A records (or AAAA for IPv6):

```
domain.com A 192.0.2.1
domain.com A 192.0.2.2
www.domain.com A 192.0.2.1
www.domain.com A 192.0.2.2
```

you put IP addresses that your WEB hosting company told you to use.

For serving email, you set up MX records that point to that company's mail server *host name*:

```
domain.com MX 10 mail1.email-hosting.com
domain.com MX 20 mail2.email-hosting.com
```

you put here *names* that your MAIL hosting company uses.

Also for mail you might need to set up SFP, DKIM, DMARC records in DNS, according to the MAIL hosting company instructions.

All you need is to be able to edit the DNS zone to set up records like this.